# one 110 outlet connected to 2 breakers on separate legs

Tags: circuit-breaker, pole

Happy 4th
I had a 15 amp breaker trip in my panel when my mother was running her sewing machine. She flipped the breaker back but later when i came home i wanted her to show me which one it was, she couldnt remember so i started flipping the breakers one by one. One of the breakers that i flipped turned off power to her sewing machine and also to the outlet in the garage but that was not the breaker that had flipped originally. So what i realized is that a 20 amp breaker on a different leg controls the outlet to her sewing machine and to the outlet in the garage. A completely other 15 amp breaker on a different leg also controls her sewing machine outlet. When the 20 amp breaker is off, the sewing machine outlet and garage outlet is off. When the 15 amp breaker is off , only her sewing machine outlet is off and the garage outlet is on. What drives me crazy is that both these breakers are on different legs which makes no sense to me. I cant find an explanation as to whats going on. The 15 amp breaker is the 1st breaker on the panel on the top right and the 20 amp breaker is the 14th breaker on the left, so this means they are on different legs. Any ideas?

Comment: Counting breakers only works if they are all full-size breakers. Upload a picture of the panel - there may be other issues that need consideration as well.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a multi-wire branch circuit (MWBC or shared neutral).  Two hots, 1 neutral, 1 ground. Saves 33% on wire.   Typically the two half-circuits are split somewhere and then go their separate ways.  **With MWBCs, the two hot wires >MUST< be on opposite legs** or else neutral would be overloaded.

It's even possible to wire an outlet "split" so each of the 2 sockets is powered by a different hot wire.  * But then a special rule can apply.

The #1 problem with MWBCs is that you shut off *the half* of the circuit you're working on, but the other half is still live, and kills you when you separate the neutral wire.  Because of this, Code requires the two breakers be **handle-tied** using an approved handle-tie.

I am surprised to hear of a MWBC that is "15A one side, 20A the other side".  That's legal as long as the 20A side *and neutral* are #12 wire.  The 15A side can be #14 or #12 wire, but since cables are all the same wire size, it's probably #12.

If a 20A (half) circuit with #12 wire powers *exactly one socket* (i.e. a standard outlet is 2 sockets), and it's the common socket (NEMA 5-15), then the breaker must be 15A even though the wire is 20A.  It's a technicality.  That is one pretty good reason to have a split 15/20A MWBC.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i thought it would be a mwbc as well but i went ahead and tested the garage outlet and sewing machine outlet separately . I tested both the hots on the garage outlet and got no reading , then i tested hot to neutral and obv i got 110 volts. I did the same with the sewing machine outlet and got the same results. I was looking to get 220v when i tested both the hots but i got 0 so that says they are on the same leg. I wanted to make sure so i went back to the breaker panel and i tested both the breakers with a voltage meter and got 220v so they are def on different legs